# Number identifying program

Tags: java

Very amateur coder here, 
I'm in the process of making a simple program to tell whether a number is positive, negative, odd or even. So far everything works apart from positive odd numbers, but cant figure out why ?

Also, how would i loop it ? would i use a for or while loop ?

Thanks

```
package weekeleven;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class week111 {

    static int number;
    static String pE;
    static String pO;
    static String nE;
    static String nO;
    static String eR;   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = -input.nextInt();      
        pE = ("Positive Even");
        pO = ("Positive Odd");
        nE = ("Negative Even");
        nO = ("Negative Odd");
        eR = ("Error"); 

        Object x = null;
        x=getSignAndParity(x);
        System.out.println(x);
}

public static String getSignAndParity(Object x) { 

    if ((number > 0) && (number % 2 == 0)) { //negative and even
        return nE;
    } else if((number < 0) && (number % 2 == 1)) { // positive and odd
        return pO;
    } else if((number < 0) && (number % 2 == 0)) { // positive and even
        return pE;
    } else if((number > 0) && (number % 2 == 1)) { // negative and odd
        return nO;
    } else { // other cases
        return eR;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: For positive odd, you have `<` instead of `>`.

Comment: `x=getSignAndParity(x);` should be `x=getSignAndParity(number);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code causing it not to work as expected.

1) You are using mod 2 on negative numbers to check if a negative number is even or odd. But that will not work. For e.g., `-7 mod 2 = -1` (which is neither 1 nor 0)

2) You are negating the user's input :

```
number = -input.nextInt();
```

and you flipped the signs `>`, `<` which is unnecessary

3) You should not be passing the `int` input as Object. You could just simply:

```
public static String getSignAndParity(int x)
```

---

Removing all the superfluous and unnecessary declarations and code, you can have  this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = input.nextInt();      
    System.out.println(getSignAndParity(number));
}

public static String getSignAndParity(int num) { 
    if(num == 0)
        return "Error";         
    String sign = num>0?"Positive":"Negative";
    String parity = Math.abs(num)%2==0?"Even":"Odd";
    return sign + " " + parity;   
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply! Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Change with this

`else if((number > 0) && (number % 2 == 1)) { // positive and odd
        return pO;
    }`

For positive odd numbers and for looping you need either existing the code or have a condition that is taken from scanner and then close the scanner.
scanner : https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class

Comment: I'm aware that i need to change that, i wrote it after all. I'm asking what is wrong with it compared to the other statements and why it isn't working ? Odd attempt at an answer.

Comment: @n0rad, check if statements of // positive and odd section, change number < 0 to number > 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to change positive odd like this:

```
else if((number < 0) && (number % 2 == -1)) { // positive and odd}
```